# How to get breakpoint to work within TypeScript fat arrow function in a promise result?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, typescript, console

So, I have a really simple Angular controller. I see a disagreement between the Chrome debugger and the console within a fat arrow function as a promise resolver. If I put a breakpoint in the handler, the source inspector can't define this.scope... however, logging it works fine. Is there some async thing going on here I don't understand, or is there a bug with scoping for fat arrow `()=>{}` function within a promise resolver function?

Or maybe, is there a bug with Chrome and TS + fat arrow in general and how it works wtih the  `.js.map` in some cases?

Also, if I manually open the `.js` file and hover while execution is still halted, I can hover over `_this.scope` and the result is correct.

It seems to be scoping it to window for the purposes of the breakpoint, but the code execution works normally.

```
class DetailController {
  scope:any;
  userModel:UserModel;

  static $inject = ['$scope','$window', 'productModel','sessionModel','userModel', '$routeParams', '$location'];
  constructor( $scope,userModel) {

    this.scope = $scope;
    this.userModel = userModel;
    this.scope.products = null;

    //if I breakpoint here, this.scope is defined

    this.userModel.getCurrentUser().then(()=> {

      this.scope.foo = 'bar';

      // if I log scope, it is defined and correct
      console.log('scope',this.scope);

      //if I breakpoint here, this.scope is undefined (hovering it says undefined)

      // etc...
      var products = this.userModel.getProducts();
      if( products.length ){
        console.log( 'prods ', this.scope );
        this.scope.products = products;
        this.scope.product = this.scope.products[0];
      }

    });
  }

  testLambda = () => {
      console.log( 'test:', this.scope ); //works
      this.scope;
      // breakpoint here fails to have proper this reference. 

  }

}

angular.module('App').controller('detailController', DetailController );
```

**update:** I added a test lambda

Comment: Do you have a `_this`-variable in the surrounding-scope of your lambda? Then this is what you are looking for. the TS-compiler has converted the lambda to a regular function.

Comment: I am aware of _this, no pun intended. What I'm saying is that normally in a lambda, I can debug right in the ts file (the breakpoint will keep forcing me to the ts version anyway). I think it may be an angular promise-related issue since `this` seems to work in any other fat arrow function. I don't want to have to keep jumping to js, and then each breakpoint goes back to ts. that's annoying. I think it's a bug here where the dubugger is not linking to the map correctly.